# Running a mpkg installer through python and subprocess.Popen objects

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a .mpkg installer on UNIX and when I run this code:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['/Path/to/File.mpkg'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
return p
```

The output is this:

```
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x11384xxx>
```

My first question is - Is there an easier way to run a mpkg installer on UNIX?
Secondly - I can't seem to figure out how to use the subprocess.Popen object to my benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I’m not sure what `mpkg` is, but there are two options.

- Either it is a self-running package, perhaps a shell script, akin to the `.run` format sometimes used for Unix software. In this case, your invocation of `Popen` is correct, as long as you have the execute permission on `File.mpkg` (check with `ls -l /Path/to/File.mpkg`). The installer should be running fine.
- Or, it is intended to be processed by a system tool, like `.deb` packages are handled with the `dpkg` program. In this case, you need something like this:

  ```
  p = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/dpkg', '-i', '/Path/to/File.deb'], ...)
  ```

  or, alternatively:

  ```
  p = subprocess.Popen('dpkg -i /Path/to/File.deb', ..., shell=True)
  ```

Now, what you do with this `Popen` object depends on what you want to achieve. If you wish to get the output of the process, you need to call [`Popen.communicate`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate), like this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
    ['/Path/to/File.mpkg'],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
(out, err) = p.communicate()
```

Now `out` contains the standard output and `err` the standard error.

If you just want to invoke the command and wait until it completes, you can also use the [`subprocess.call`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) shortcut.

Comment: You were right about the system tool. Once I included that inside the 'command' it ran and unpackaged perfectly. Running `subprocess.Popen([])` and `subprocess.call([])` both worked. Before it didn't know what else to do so it created an object. Cheers.